# Why does my T-SQL query return differently in separate windows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

**UPDATE**
Right, so I have worked out the problem.  It's caused by the expression:

```
I.DeliveryWCDate - DATEPART(dw, I.DeliveryWCDate) + 2
```

This is inserting into a field with a foreign key to a table containing valid dates for Mondays.  However, the expression is somehow returning dates for Tuesdays, which is breaking the foreign key.  As this is a piece of legacy code, I can't quite work out the logic of subtracting the weekday value and adding 2.  I think this may have something to do with ensuring that a Monday date gets inserted to the table, but this isn't working.

I have a stored procedure that transfers sales orders from one system to another.  This proc has a statement that creates stock records.  If the stock records aren't created, the sales orders get cancelled.

When the stock insert is run in line with the proc, no records are inserted into the stock table.  However, if I run the SQL in the proc up to that statement, then paste the stock insert into to a separate query window connected to the same database, it will insert records into the stock table.  Why would the same SQL behave in two different ways?

I have tried adding explicit transaction statements, creating separate procs for each section of code, calling the code either through a main proc or as explicit code using SQL agent.

```
SELECT SO.SalesOrderID, I.ClientID, I.RMContract
, DeliveryWCDate=I.DeliveryWCDate - DATEPART(dw, I.DeliveryWCDate) + 2
, I.Version, I.UnitID, I.DistNo, I.LeafletDesignNo, BarcodeLBS=MAX(I.Barcode)
FROM ImportLine I
JOIN SalesOrder SO ON 
                    SO.CMOrderNo = I.CustomerOrderNo 
                    AND SO.SourceSystemID = I.SourceSystemID
JOIN DistType D ON SO.DistTypeID=D.DistTypeID 
    AND CASE WHEN I.DistType = 'Instore' THEN 'Instore' ELSE 'Other' END
        = CASE WHEN D.DistType = 'Instore' THEN 'Instore' ELSE 'Other' END
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Cancelled=0) S ON 
    S.ClientID = I.ClientID
    AND S.SalesOrderID = SO.SalesOrderID
    AND S.RMContract = I.RMContract
    AND S.DistNo = I.DistNo
    AND ISNULL(S.LeafletDesignNo,'') = ISNULL(I.LeafletDesignNo,'')
    AND S.DeliveryWCDate = (I.DeliveryWCDate - DATEPART(dw, I.DeliveryWCDate) + 2)
    AND UPPER(S.Version) = UPPER(I.Version) 
left join dbo.WeekCommencing wc on I.DeliveryWCDate - DATEPART(dw, I.DeliveryWCDate) + 2 = wc.WeekCommencing
WHERE S.ClientID IS NULL
AND -- Do not load confirmed sales orders more than once
SO.AllowImport = 1 AND SO.Cancelled=0
and
wc.WeekCommencing is not null
GROUP BY SO.SalesOrderID, I.ClientID, I.RMContract, I.DeliveryWCDate, I.Version, I.UnitID, I.DistNo, I.LeafletDesignNo
```

The select statement should return 1400ish records.  However, via the stored proc, it returns nothing.  When it is run completely isolated from other code, it returns the records.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The edit wasn't intended as an answer, just to add extra information.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have worked out what the problem was.  I had included a calculated dates to populate the date parameters used in the procedure.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @SeedDate DATETIME2 = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE);
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = DATEADD(ww, -1, @SeedDate);
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME2 = DATEADD(ww, 3, @SeedDate);
```

The use of SET DATEFIRST = 1 is causing the expression to return dodgy values.  By changing this to DATEFIRST = 7 and modifying the expression for @SeedDate, all seems to be ok.

I hadn't appreciated that this would have had an impact on the code in the stored proc.